# Jetpack Navigation: ActionBar back arrow only for specific fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, architecture, navigation, android-jetpack

I have an app with a bottom navigation, it is the main navigation between list (like Projects, Tags, etc.), all of those fragments should be equivalent, top level `Fragments`. The navigation is working perfectly, it was setup with.

```
    bottom_navigation.let { bottomNavigationView ->
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController)
    }
```

From the different top level fragments I would like to navigatie to lower level fragments, those should have back arrow in the action bar. I can connect the navigation with the action bar with the following code.

```
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
```

The problem is that in this case all fragments gets a back arrow, all the top level fragments as well (except the one what I marked as start destination in the navigation editor). Is it possible to mark more fragments as the start fragment or mark some fragments in navigation to not get this back arrow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this with:

```
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.top_level_fragment1, R.id.top_level_fragment2, R.id.top_level_fragment3))

setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

By passing the list of ids of the destination (fragments) with the `AppBarConfiguration` your navController will consider these as top level (no back arrow).

Here's the [link to the relevant android developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration).